# How can i pass my props when using react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a react router Link that sends me to a component called New

```
 <Link to="/New"> New  </Link>
```

Here is the routing configuration for New

```
 <Route path="/New" component={New}></Route>
```

Now my question is this, how can I pass props to the New Item Component.

Normally I would do this `<New Onchange={this.handleChange} onsubmit={this.handleSubmit}/>`

Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the component into an arrow function

```
<Route path="/New" component={(props) => <New props={props}/>}></Route>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use React Router v5.1+, you can actually use the `Route` component like this:

```
<Route path="/path">
    <Component {whatever props you want to pass} />
</Route>
```

To pass props through the `Link` component:

```
<Link to={{
  pathname: '/new',
  state: {
    propsToPass: 'whatever'
  }
}}>New</Link>
```

Then in your New component:

```
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'

const location = useLocation();

console.log(location.state.propsToPass) // logs 'whatever'
```

Comment: Is there a way i can pass the props in this page (page where the props i want to pass lives in)`<Link to="/New"> New  </Link>` instead of  here (App.Js)`<Route path="/New" component={New}></Route>`

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using render with a callback.

```
<Route path="/New" render={(props) => <New text="Hello, " {...props} />} />
```

Hope this is what you are looking for.
Hope this helps!